# Python: Get instances of an object (via for loop ..?)

Tags: python, class, instance

I want to access all the instances of my user class using a dictionary.
I initiate (right word?) the instances like this, with `save_dat` being the dictionary.

```
for a in save_dat:
    a = user(a,save_dat[a])
    a.some_method
```

that works fine.
However, later I want to access those instances again. my idea:

```
for a in save_dat:
    a.some_method
```

doesn't work, `error: 'str' object has no attribute 'name'`
but I have already made those entries in `save_dat` user instances!?
I cant really do `a = user(a,save_dat[a])` again, since this would overwrite the changed attributes of some of those instances (i think ..), and they should already be user instances?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (supposing that `user` is either a function that returns an instance, or the name of a class that starts with a lowercase letter):

```
users = {}
for a, data in save_dat.items():
    users[a] = user(a, data)
    users[a].some_method ()
```

And later:

```
for a in users.values():
    a.some_method ()
```

If you actually want to update your dictionary instead of creating a new dictionary `users`, try this:

```
save_dat = {key: user(key, value) for key, value in save_dat.items() }
```

And then:

```
for a in save_dat.values():
    a.some_method ()
```

Comment: yes! That works! Thanks!!

but why did my code not work, and what is the key idea that makes this code work? where is the decisive difference?

Comment: The difference is that in your code you don't store the result of `user()` anywhere. You assign it to the local variable `a`, overwriting it in each iteration, and which ceases to exist once the loop finishes. Then in your second loop you iterate again over the original dictionary as though you had never called `user()`.

Answer (score 0):

What I could understand is that with `a = user(a,save_dat[a])` you are trying to save the instances in the `save_dat` dictionary.

But doing `a = user(a,save_dat[a])` wouldn't work how you want it.
For example:

```
some_dict = { 1: 3, 2: 4}
for i in some_dict:
    i = 5
```

This doesn't change the dictionary to `{ 1: 5, 2: 5}`, rather the dictionary doesn't change at all.

For changing the dictionary we have to do something like this:

```
some_dict = { 1: 3, 2:4}
for i in some_dict:
    some_dict[i] = 5
```

So, what you should do is:

```
for a in save_dat:
    save_dat[a] = user(a,save_dat[a])
    save_dat[a].some_method
```